# three.js - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'makeRotationAxis' of undefined

Tags: three.js

```
    var rotationMatrix = new THREE.Matrix4(); 
                var position = new THREE.Vector3( 1000, 1000, 0 );
                var angle = Math.PI / 4;
                var axis = new THREE.Vector3( 1, 0.5, 0 ).normalize();

            function render() {

                /** Adds a rotation of rad to the obj's rotation about world's axis */                      
                rotationMatrix.makeRotationAxis( axis, angle ).multiplyVector3( position );
                    tubeMesh.matrix = rotationMatrix;                   
                    tubeMesh.rotation.getRotationFromMatrix(rotationMatrix, tubeMesh.scale);
                        renderer.render( scene, camera );
                    }
```

I've used this code from these URLs:

- [issue on GitHub](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/2185)
- [question on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10941828/how-fast-is-the-jscript-garbage-collector-three-js-matrix-rotations)

I am getting the error **"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'makeRotationAxis' of undefined"**. Here `rotationMatrix` is defined as `THREE.Matrix4()` and it is same as the code given in above links. I am using r51 of three.js library.

Comment: Vector3's `.getRotationFromMatrix( matrix, scale )` is changed to Vector3's `.setEulerFromRotationMatrix( matrix, order )` from r50 of three.js

Comment: Do I need to add `Matrix4.js` file ?